# Appium driver for Capybara

Tags: ruby, testing, capybara, appium

Is it possible to use **Capybara** with custom driver, which will talk with **Appium** ruby client underneath?

I'm aware that both of this tools communicate with webdriver directly, however they targeting different environments (desktop and mobile) therefore resulting API of Capybara and Appium differs.

Despite of that, I'm still thinking if there are cases, when using Appium as Capybara driver would make sense. Such driver would provide some extra mobile-only API and possibly do not implement everything from `Capybara::Driver::Base`, however it might be possible to create **one test scenario**, which would run on dekstop and mobile browsers.

So my question is - are there any examples of using Appium in such way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We decided to create the gem ***appium_capybara*** while using the ***appium_lib*** gem. This enables the use of Appium with ***Capybara***. It is located on git at https://github.com/appium/appium_capybara and on rubygems at https://rubygems.org/gems/appium_capybara.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a way. :)

It was quite a journey but turned out to be quite simple in the end.

```
Capybara.register_driver :ipad do |app|
  caps = {
    :device => "iPad Simulator",
    :browserName => 'iOS',
    :platform => 'Mac',
    :version => '6.1',
    :app => 'safari'
    }

    Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(app, {:browser => :remote, :url => "http://localhost:4723/wd/hub/", :desired_capabilities => caps})
  end
Capybara.default_driver = :ipad
```

I use this with Xcode version 4.6.3 and Appium version 1.1.0. I tried with the latest Appium but it somehow broke my setup.

I drew my inspiration from this page: http://www.matthewbussa.com/2013/10/cross-browsercross-platform-automated.html

Hope this helps